# How do i use python to remove backgrounds of multiple images?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, syntax-error, rembg

I want to know how to remove the background of multiple images at once

I tried this:

```py
from rembg import remove
from PIL import Image
import os

for i in os.listdir(r'C:\\Users\\Carlo Karim\\Desktop\\folder'):
input_path = r'C:\\Users\\Carlo Karim\\Desktop\\folder' + i
output_path = r'C:\\Users\\Carlo Karim\\Documents\\output'

input = Image.open(input_path)
output = remove(input)
output.save(output_path)
```

but it gave me an error at line 6 and I can't seem to make this work.

Comment: your input is probably wrong, it should be `input_path = r'C:\\Users\\Carlo Karim\\Desktop\\folder\\' + i`

Comment: It's impossible to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 things to note

1. Your input path needs \\ at the end
2. Your output string needs to be a path with an image extension
3. Output needs to be PNG for transparency

   ```
    from rembg import remove
    from PIL import Image
    import os

    for i in os.listdir(r'C:\\Users\\Carlo Karim\\Desktop\\folder'):

        j = i.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)[0]
        input_path = r'C:\\Users\\Carlo Karim\\Desktop\\folder\\' + i
        output_path = r'C:\\Users\\Carlo Karim\\Documents\\output\\' + j + ".png"

        input = Image.open(input_path)
        output = remove(input)
        output.save(output_path)
   ```